# set Database and Schema name using variable in select statement within snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to set database and schema name using variable and a static table name. I don't want to use dynamic sql for the same.
Below is the code which i tried and not working.

```
DECLARE

    V_RET VARCHAR(1000) := '';

    schema_name := 'EDWSTGP.DBU_CDS';

BEGIN

    select first_name INTO V_RET from table(:schema_name||'.EMPLOYEE') limit 1;

    RETURN V_RET;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are trying to do in the way you are trying to do it. You have to construct the string containing the FQN for the table and then use that string in the SQL statement e.g.

```
DECLARE
    V_RET VARCHAR(1000) := '';
    schema_name := 'EDWSTGP.DBU_CDS';
    table_name VARCHAR(1000);

BEGIN
    table_name := :schema_name||'.EMPLOYEE';
    select first_name INTO V_RET from table(:table_name) limit 1;
    RETURN V_RET;
END;
```

Comment: That wouldn't help cause if i have multiple selects and multiple tables so i have to define a variable for each of the table used in select.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with what you are actually trying to achieve and the requirements any answer needs to meet. Being given an answer and then saying it doesn’t meet some requirement that you haven’t mentioned is not that helpful

Answer (score 0):

Answer is :

DECLARE
V_RET VARCHAR(1000) := '';

```
destination_tbl VARCHAR(50);

schema_name := 'EDWSTGP.DBU_CDS';
```

BEGIN

```
SELECT CONCAT(:schema_name,''.tblName'') INTO :destination_tbl;

select first_name INTO :V_RET from IDENTIFIER(:destination_tbl) limit 1;

RETURN V_RET;
```

END;